# NAT with port forwarding on same interface

Tags: networking, nat, forwarding

I have some issues with the port forwarding on same interface.

I have server1 with the public IP 5.1.1.1 and one company publish a MySQL database with IP 10.1.1.1 through VPN reached only by server1.

I need to connect to MySQL from any client that knows the server1 IP. I think to NAT the inbound connection at server1 port 5000 to 10.1.1.1:3306 destination.

`clientx ------- server1(5.1.1.1) --- VPN ------ mysql(10.1.1.1:3306)`

I execute the following  statements on server1, but it doesn't work.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 5000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.1.1:3306
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 10.1.1.1 --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: You need to show the entire firewall configuration.

Comment: I don't have firewall.  I know it's unsecured system. I try this configuration with an simulation in LAN but doesn't work too.

Comment: Could you provide the output of the following commands: `iptables -t nat -S`, `iptables -S`, if those don't work, please provide, `iptables -t nat -Ln` and `iptables -Ln`. Also provide the output of `netstat -rn`.
You can sanitize IP addresses of course, but please do so in a consistent manner.

Comment: Is the VPN in the same network as the mysql server?